# Can I trigger TFS 2020 in WebStorm

Tags: tfs, webstorm

I am using WebStorm IDE for Angular 9 development. There is no problem by git source control but now I want to use Team Foundation Server 2020 in WebStorm. Can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Please try using Microsoft plugin for TFS Integration - https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7981-azure-devops.
See https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/01/end-of-support-for-tfs-2014-and-older/ for more info